# Exclusion Script in Journey Builder SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

We want to implement a frequency capping mechanism which restricts the number of communications sent to a subscriber. We have an automation which periodically updates the number of sends to a subscriber in a DE.

The frequency capping functionality is easily possible while sending emails by using exclusions scripts in Journey Builder or standalone sends etc.

How do we implement such a scenario in SMS sends? Any pointers?

Comment: MobileConnect doesn't send an empty SMS. I'd recommend wrapping your content with IF and ELSE where you'd include nothing when the criteria is met and SMS would have null value, hence SMS won't be sent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RaiseError will not work in MobileConnect, however, MobileConnect won't send an SMS with empty content. Alternatively, you could try wrapping the SMS content with `IF` statements to produce empty SMS content when the criteria are met.

Below example will do a lookup on your Subscriber Log DE to see if the mobile number has previously been sent any SMS. If the row count is less than 1 then it will show the SMS content or else no content will be displayed.

**For example:**

```
%%[
VAR @SendlogDE
SET @SendlogDE = LookupRows("SendlogDE","MobileNumber",MOBILE_NUMBER)

IF RowCount(@SendlogDE) < 1 THEN 
]%%
SMS Content Here
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Thanks Brad. This works. Will the "not sent" SMS still result in a super message consumption?